# Winterbash 2017

Tags: discussion, event, winterbash

Winterbash 2017 is near

https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/

Do we opt this year again for this?

Comment: No better place to weart fancy winter hats than MagentoSE +1 :)

Comment: Yes, It should be  :) but couldn't find the official source

Comment: oh great , i'm shivering here.... need some hats to cover ;)

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I also feel the same , MagentoSE is best place to wear hats

Comment: @KeyurShah I also search in meta.stackexchange for this but couldn't find any source

Comment: @KeyurShah here you go : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360022/2017-winterbash

Comment: Thanks for sharing link :) @BabyinMagento

Comment: And Answer is yes we opted again this time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes we opted this year

[image]

Comment: Congratulations for hat, when you ll give party :)

Comment: @BabyinMagento come Gujarat for party

Comment: sure bhai, i ll come there once elections are done......

Comment: Ok just let me know when you come

Comment: yeah , definitely.....